# SQL Server Procedure with Filename as a Parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, xml-parsing

I have a SQL Server procedure and I would like to have the file name as the parameter.

My code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XMLTOSQLTABLE1 @NewName nvarchar(50)
AS
  TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo.Student]

  DECLARE @x XML
  SELECT @x = P
  FROM OPENROWSET (BULK @NewName, SINGLE_BLOB) AS Student(P)

  DECLARE @hdoc int

  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument 
    @hdoc OUTPUT, 
    @x

  INSERT INTO [dbo.Student] 
  SELECT * 
  FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/class_list/student',2)
  WITH (
    name varchar(100), 
    grade varchar(100))

  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
GO
```

I would like to have the file name and the column names to be my parameter so I could easily input any XML file into the database by simply executing the procedure with the filename and column names as my parameters.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do, do you want to create a stored procedure with two parameters?

Answer (score 1):

As far as your code is concerned, you have to pay attention to a few things for it to work.

Let's see:

1. `TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo.Student]`

   I believe you are truncating table Student in default schema.
   So, it should be

   ```
   TRUNCATE TABLE Student
   ```

   or

   ```
   TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Student
   ```

   Since you don't have no special chars or keywords in table name, forget 
   the square brackets.
2. `SELECT @x = P FROM OPENROWSET (BULK @NewName, SINGLE_BLOB) AS Student(P)`

   You can't parameterize `OPENROWSET BULK` file reading. 
   Only way to do it is using dynamic SQL, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966922/how-can-i-specify-the-path-to-a-file-dynamically-in-openrowsetbulk).

   Another problem is assigning a varbinary BLOB to an xml variable, which
   won't work without type conversion, like `CAST(P as xml)`. Just pay attention
   to what you are really loading because non-well-formatted XML segment will
   throw an error here.
3. Another problem is using `sp_xml_preparedocument` procedure. Do you really need it?
   Using this kind of XML parsing can limit your xml resources. Also, if you forget
   to call (or skip because of an error) `sp_xml_removedocument` you *will* get errors
   because of this. AFAIK, server restart will help here.

   Note: sp_xml_preparedocument is vulnerable, so pay attention where your XML files
   come from.

When you clear this out, a few question stay open: what kind of a second parameter (column names) do you need and why? Should it be an XML parameter? Should it use for a hint what kind of children should be extracted from bulk loaded xml root?

When you sort this out, I believe that a stored procedure could be constructed, but not without some dynamic expression.