# return a file from a directory using sql

Tags: sql-server, file, file-io

I am writing an add-on to a current system and need to get image data. However the image data gets saved in a directory on the server side of the client/server application. I want to read the file from the directory and return it as an image field using SQL Server which is also on the Server.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966922/how-can-i-specify-the-path-to-a-file-dynamically-in-openrowsetbulk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a CLR storedprocedure (c#) which reads the contents of the image file and returns it as a varbinary(MAX).