# OPENROWSET: sp_executesql statement failing at @param

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, filepath, openrowset, sp-executesql

I am developing a program to pull in the `XML` file that `WordPress` enables you to download (essentially a backup copy).

At this point I was automating the process to allow frequent backup of my data on `SQL Server`, and for some reason I am stuck at developing the query to run the `OPENROWSET` where the `XML` file will be located.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@fstring NVARCHAR(MAX)'
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'C:\[FilePath]\Reviews\thehesperian2016-07-29.xml'

SET @SQL = 
N'INSERT INTO #Temp (Extract_Date, XMLDATA)
SELECT GETDATE()
     , A.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK @fstring, SINGLE_BLOB, CODEPAGE = ' + '''RAW''' + ') AS A'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
                 , @ParamDefinition
                 , @fstring = @string
```

The error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@fstring'.
```

I can turn this into a simple query on a table in the predicate, so I have reason to suspect it is the way the `filepath` is read.
I've spent a few hours racking my brain trying to figure out why this is wrong. While I COULD use `QUOTENAME` as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966922/how-can-i-specify-the-path-to-a-file-dynamically-in-openrowsetbulk) in the BULKINSERT, I was hoping to embed all of that in the dynamic SQL (thus still use `sp_executesql`)

What or why am I doing this wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
- Regards,

**ANSWER**

[OPENROWSET - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) declares in its own paragraph:

> OPENROWSET does not accept variables for its arguments.

`QUOTENAME` is sufficient, although I did run a few minor `REPLACE`functions anyways.

Comment: In your dynamic SQL @fstring is being seen as a literal, not a variable.

Comment: @scsimon right, forgot to mention I was calling fstring via the proc parameter, so SQL Server shouldn't be guessing from how I understand it.

Comment: You'll have to Concat with + '''@var''' +  for dynamic SQL but still not sure about it being in OPENROWSET. I don't think it'll work

Comment: @scsimon I tried, but alas, there is no method. Still, QUOTENAME is just as useful. :) Thanks for the help, your first comment hit the spot where I was off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data file path the OPENROWSET function does not allow a parameter.  Instead, build the needed string with the literal:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(MAX) = N'C:\[FilePath]\Reviews\thehesperian2016-07-29.xml';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = 
N'INSERT INTO #Temp (Extract_Date, XMLDATA)
SELECT GETDATE()
     , A.*
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@string, '''') + ', SINGLE_BLOB, CODEPAGE = ''RAW'') AS A';
EXEC sp_execute @SQL;

--EXECUTE(@SQL);
```

**UPDATE:**

Added QUOTENAME in case the provided file path is from an untrusted source.  Also, note that [OPENROWSET queries are not autoparameterized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx).  It makes no difference whether one executes the query with `sp_executesql` or `EXECUTE` here.

Comment: This does defeat the point, which was to use sp_executesql. Also, I flubbed by not mentioning @fstring is called in the proc as a parameter...so in theory, SQL server should be able to treat it as a variable, right?

Comment: @clifton_h, you can use `sp_executesql @SQL` instead of `EXEC(@SQL)` if that is your preference but there is no requirement to do so without a parameter.  Only a literal string is allowed as the file name argument.  `OPENROWSET` doesn't allow parameters, AFAIK.

Comment: I would accept your answer, except it needs to cleanse the variable first via `QUOTENAME(@string, NCHAR(39) )`. to avoid malicious use.

Comment: Good point about the AdHoc, unless I was using this in a SSIS package (where the filepath would be reused again), but that is highly unlikely. guess I passed that section on MSDN. Thanks!